# Why doesn't Alert.alert() work in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/@miralis/bad-apple
Check pressNumber. I want to Alert.alert("Nice work!") when "if" returns true, and ("Try again!") when it returns false, but Alert.alert() doesn't work.

Comment: Upon trying the link you provided, it seems to work. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work like @blankart said, I guess just because you declare a random `num` and then you can't catch the correct number each time. Just change the num to a real number like this and input it. You can go into the true statement.

PS:You could console out the num and number to check the original statement.

```js
const [number, setNumber] = useState();
  const pressNumber = () => {
    const num = (Math.random() * 1).toFixed();      //random each time is different.
    //if(num == number) {
    if(number == 5) {                  //  and then input 5 is the correct to nice work.
      console.log("Nice work!");
      Alert.alert("Nice work!")
    }
    else {
     console.log(num)                  // console the num
     console.log(number)               // console the number
     console.log("Try again!");
     Alert.alert("Try again!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain where is not useful or there is any problem let you downvote?